# Tool for design android ui elements

Tags: android, user-interface

i have just started to study android a few days a go. 
i want to design **nice android** elements and i don't know there is any tool to help me do it?
if have any tool, please tell me
thank so much.

Answer (score 0):

Please visit following link, Its the best one i found on net. Very user-friendly too.

http://www.droiddraw.org/